# How to clear chat window of previous messages

Tags: botframework

I have an Agent Dashboard where an agent can talk to multiple customers.

(First the customer talks to the bot, then may trigger hand-off to agent. That's when the agent is connected to the customer. Our underlying system is based on [ankitbko's](http://ankitbko.github.io/2017/03/human-handover-bot/) agent handoff.)

From the agent's side, I can reuse my chat windows after ending customer conversations. However, the chat from the previous customer is visible in the same window. I would like to clear that chat window before starting the chat between agent and customer. How can I achieve that?

I tried setting the botConnection to null then assigning it a new connection but that doesn't seem to do anything; it doesn't clear the chat window... it also doesn't break anything because the next customer chat works well.

```
            botConnection = null;
            botConnection = GetNewBotConnection();
            BotChat.App({
                botConnection: botConnection,
                user: { id: user.id, name: user.name },
                bot: bot
            }, document.getElementById("customerchatwindow" + id));
```

Comment: Did you use [Direct Line secret or token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#secrets-and-tokens) to initiate the botConnection?

Comment: The easiest way to clear the chat window is to just refresh the page itself. To do this without refreshing the whole page, I would recommend making a custom version of the [webchat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#customizing-webchat) to add that feature.

Comment: @FeiHan I used the secret

Comment: @MarkB I will look into that. thanks! refreshing the whole page is not an option for us since there are multiple chat windows in that one page.